# Некорректное отображение комментария об откате в очереди на переоткрытие

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

[Наткнулся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/242815) в очереди на переоткрытие на пункт со странным описанием правки:

> — 5 часов назад — Rollback to [b8225947-51aa-4b20-a8f2-1d4b0bc9a13c]
>
> [image: — 5 часов назад — Rollback to [b8225947-51aa-4b20-a8f2-1d4b0bc9a13c]]

Если же перейти к вопросу и посмотреть его историю правок, то там всё нормально

> Откат к версии 2
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]